# Blender 2.8 Fbx Export - Weights shifting?

Tags: weight-painting, unity, .fbx

It seems like in my latest export (for some reason I can’t detect) has an issue with weights. Below is a screenshot from Unity following an Fbx export of the mesh and rig, with animations.

[image]

In Blender, all investigations suggest that all the needed vertices are painted appropriately.

[image]

No amount of ‘Normalize All’ seems to reveal the source of this influence (figuring it may been another bone) and my attempts to make the entire arm very heavily painted for the bone associated doesn’t seem to fix anything. Any tips would be great.